# The WPF designer does not load automatically

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

The WPF designer does not load automatically.
I have to load it manually after debug

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dcuSz.jpg)

=> Translated text for image

Throw exception: System.Resources.MissingSatelliteAssemblyException :
The name "Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools" for the fallback culture.Satellite assemblies with SurfaceDesigner.resources.dll, Version=16.0.0.0, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d5a3a" could not be found or loaded. It's a general installation problem. Please reinstall or repair the application.

*Solution*
My case is need Language pack
Visual Studio Installer - Language pack - fallback culture language installation

Comment: "Please reinstall or repair the application" - did you already try this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to install: Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Extensibility -Version 16.10.31320.204

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Extensibility

Comment: not worked but Thank you

Comment: Figure out : 
Visual Studio Installer - Language pack - fallback culture language installation

Answer (score 0):

You could try to find the xaml designer process XDesProc.exe and use the task manager to kill it. Then reopen the file, the designer should be able to display. If not, please install the update or reinstall visual studio.